# Derivation of Slater and Koster Table

Tags: tight-binding

Im currently struggling with the description of the Slater-Koster (SK) method. I should calculate the SK table. But I do not know how they calculated the formulas. There are some other references which have used the same method to generate the same table for d and f orbitals. Here are the references

J. C. Slater and G. F. Koster, Phys. Rev. 94, 1498 (1954).

R. R. Sharma, Phys. Rev. B 19, 2813 (1979).

K. Lendi, Phys, Rev. B 9, 2433 (1974).

and

General Formulas for the Slater-Koster Table, Journal of Computational Physics 110, 187-189 (1994).

I would appreciate if someone can help me about the approach of them. What is the starting point?